# Expected value of total points in a competition

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

The question is as follows:

> Two friends, Mike and Robert, each take a $9$ question exam for a chemistry competition.  Mike answers each question correctly with probability $\frac{2}{3}$ and Robert answers each question correctly with probability $\frac{3}{5}.$  All answers are independent of other answers.  Each friend receives a point for each question he answers correctly and which the other friend does not answer correctly.  Let $X$ be the total number of points at the end of the competition.  What is $\mathbb{E}\left [ X \right ]?$

My initial thought was to find the p.m.f. of the random variable $X$ and then use the fact that 
$$\mathbb{E}\left [ X \right ]=\sum_{i=0}^{9}x_{i}p(x_{i}).$$
However, the probabilities seem way too complicated.  For example, 
$$\mathbb{P}(X=7)=\binom{9}{7}\left ( \frac{1}{3} \right )^{2}\left ( \frac{2}{3} \right )^{7}\left ( \frac{2}{5} \right )^{9}+ \ ...$$
Adding all of  these would take a long time - and this is just for $\mathbb{P}(X=7)!$  Plus, since the question says nothing about ties, I am not sure what to do with those as well.

Is there any easier way to appraoch this?  Am I overthinking it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what the question means is that on any given question Mike only gets a point if he gets it correct and Robert gets it wrong.

The probability if this happening is always $$P_{mike} = \frac 23 \times \frac 25=\frac 4{15}
$$
Mike's score is distributed binomially with $n=9;p=\frac 4{15}$

Robert's score score is distributed binomially with $n=9;p=\frac 35\times \frac1{3}=\frac 15
$

for binomial distributions ...$$\mathbb{E}\left [ X \right ] = np $$